# Git deleting files from remote

Tags: git, openshift

I have a website. Users can add a picture their profile. So, my website keeping these files in a folder. But, my local git clone only has this image folder without images inside.

When I use "git push" command, it's working great but deleting all images added by users.. How can I solve this problem? [Or, how can I add images (added by users) to git tracking?]

(I'm using openShift)

Comment: Why don't you add this folder to the git ignore file? This means that the folder will be ignored and shouldn't be considered in commits

Comment: `.gitignore`.....

Comment: I've tried gitignore like this: "photos/", I've deleted cache and push it but in this case, my photos folder is deleted from remote.

Comment: git does not really version folders. Why do you need the folder if you ignore the contents from the folder?

Comment: You probably should _not_ be pushing images to your repository, because Git doesn't handle binaries well.  If the remote is already blocking your images, then good, someone else already thought of this problem.

Comment: Guys, git deleting images added by users.. This is the problem. when I pull the remote content, it doesn't pull my_folder's content. because git doesn't track contents added by users.. so, I've tried gitignore with "photos/" or "photos/*" but in this case, git deletes my photos folder completely from remote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR to save persistent files.  Use a symlink in link it to one of your folders in the repo.

Edit

post_deploy example

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ".................Starting 'post_deploy' Action Hook..................................."
echo ".................attempting 'uploads' setting up symlink........................"
echo "................................................................................"
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/<path to static folder>
ln -s $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploads uploads
echo ".................creating 'uploads' completed........................"
echo "................................................................................"
```

Comment: But in this case, symlink will be deleted. Am I wrong?

Comment: I use the post_deploy action hook to create it on every git push

Comment: I added an example file in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can either skip that folder when you run `git add` command or the better add it to `.gitignore` file like this:

```
your_folder/*
```

Comment: I tried this now again. Then git push.. And I've saved a picture to remote with my website ui. Then git push again.. Ta Ta.. Saved picture deleted again.. :(

Comment: Are you sure that you pushed `.gitignore` file?

Comment: yes, sure. I've checked with Filezilla. Already, when I use gitignore like in your answer, as I said; ignored folder is removing from remote.

Answer (score 0):

Git works on files, not on folders. And if a folder does not contain any files, git assumes the folder itself should not be present either.

The most commonly used solution is an empty file `.gitkeep` in the folder that needs to remain. Then, in `.gitignore`, you add the following:

```
images_folder/*
!images_folder/.gitkeep
```

This tells git to ignore all files in the images folder, except for the one file named `.gitkeep`. (So that file must be committed too.) Then there's no reason for git to remove the folder, so your images will remain.

Comment: First, really thank you. I've tried but it didn't worked. I guess, problem is about my subfolders in images_folder. I've folders named user_id. And photos are included them. For example: "images_folder/23582385/firstphoto.png". So, I've tried this case: `images_folder/* images_folder/*/* !images_folder/.gitkeep. It keeps images_folder, but deleting subfolders and their contents when I pushed git.

Comment: I've changed my way. So, I'm using this way to store photos: "images_folder/28358523.png", and I'm using your gitignore code. My gitignore file is in main directory. So, images_folder is in the main directory too. I've created .gitkeep file in images_folder too. But still, when I use git push, images are deleting added by users with web interface. it just kept .gitkeep file in images_folder directory.